# Equal borders on touching div container "table"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a makeshift table of items that are rounded and equal borders by removing the bottom border from every container that ins't the first or the last.

What I'm trying to achieve, is when I hover, I'd like to have the entire "container" have a white border but it's not really possible at the moment because of the zero border. Does anyone have any suggestions? I'm assuming I have to do this with javascript.

[Here is what I have so far (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/5TKjB/140/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="item-container">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="item-container">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="item-container">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="item-container">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="item-container">
    5
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body { 
  background-color:#000;
 }

 #container { width:500px;}

.item-container { border:3px solid #7F7F7F;color:#7F7F7F;padding:10px;width:100%;border-bottom:0 }
.item-container:not(:first-child) { border-bottom:0; }

.item-container:hover { border:3px solid #fff;cursor:pointer;color:#fff; }

.item-container:first-child { border-top-right-radius:3px;border-top-left-radius:3px; }
.item-container:last-child { border-bottom:3px solid #7F7F7F;border-bottom-right-radius:3px;border-bottom-left-radius:3px; }
```

Comment: you mean all the border ? including in the inside one ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I'm not quite sure what you mean

Comment: when you hover what sould happen ? :) what border should be white

Comment: The top border of the previous child and the left, right, and bottom border of the hovered element. Obviously that isn't possible so not sure what the best course of action is @TemaniAfif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create the border differently:

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}

#container {
  width: 500px;
  color: #7F7F7F;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid;
}

.item-container {
  border: 3px solid #7F7F7F;
  border-bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.item-container:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
  right: -3px;
  left: -3px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #7F7F7F;
}

#container .item-container:hover {
  border-color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: 1s;
}

#container .item-container:hover::after {
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item-container">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="item-container">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="item-container">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="item-container">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="item-container">
    5
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Was it your intention to have every border show on hover?

Comment: @TravisJ because the OP said **I'd like to have the entire "container" have a white border** .. and am note sure what he want, so made a try and we will see ;)

Comment: I believe he was indicating he wanted each `item-container` to have a white border. However, he wants the entire border between elements to be highlighted during hover, and not just half.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much Temani this makes perfect sense.

Comment: Bonus points: if you add a transition property the bottom border comes in way faster then the others. Any idea on why this is?

Comment: @bryan ok will check this ;)

Comment: Wow man, you just keep killing it! Thank you. I would put it not on the :hover section's so that it fades out as well

Comment: @bryan well it won't work :) as the fade out is a bit tricky in this way .. the main issue is with the z-index as we have element overlapping which make the transition not easy to handle